# Where to find basic Predicates like greaterThan for Guava?

Tags: java, guava, predicates

I am using the guava library and have noticed that a very useful [Predicate](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/index.html) is not defined - "greater than".  Is there another place I should be looking for basic predicates like this, or am I doomed to create my own functional support jar that includes things like this, and import it into all of my projects?  Is there a reason they wouldn't include this,but would take the time to do a bunch of other predicates (In the Predicates class)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the `Predicate` interface and the various utility methods to filter collections with a Predicate, Guava provides a core you can build upon.

The `Predicates` class lets you create some commonly used predicates. I guess you could do a request for enhancement in the issue tracker, as suggested by Mike, but I'm not sure they would add it, since Guava strives for a high power-to-weight ratio.

If they were to add the "greaterThan" predicate, they would also need to add "greaterOrEqualThan", "lesserThan", "lesserOrEqualThan"... This would be useful, but this is a lot of "API bloat" for a Predicate that only takes one line to implement. Worth a try, though.

A better solution might be to have an open-source project that extends Guava with all the "nice-to-have" functionality that is not available in Guava proper. We could call it "guava-leftovers" or something ;) Or maybe ask the [Biscotti](http://code.google.com/p/biscotti/) project to add such utility methods (they already have some "nice-to-have" functionality that's not in Guava).

Comment: Yeah, i guess since they wrote it they get to decide what's "bloat" and what's core.  As far as the one liner argument goes, I would argue that you don't need all 3 logical operations (and, or, not) when those can all be implemented in one line as combinations of "nand" predicates :)

Comment: Good point. Actually, I think I sounded kind of harsh when I said it would be "API bloat" to add such predicates. I believe these would be quite useful. I really like the idea of having a "Range" class that produces these predicates, though (see Sean Patrick Floyd's answer). It would also work for intervals, and so on.

Answer (score 15):

[Range](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Range.html) and <s>[Ranges](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ranges.html)</s> (update: the static methods on `Ranges` have been folded into `Range` as of Guava 14.0) have now been added for r10. You'll be able to just do:

```
Iterable<Integer> positive = Iterables.filter(numbers, Range.greaterThan(0));
```

`Range`s have a lot of other powerful functionality, including the ability to view a `Range` as a contiguous `ImmutableSortedSet` over a discrete domain:

```
ContiguousSet<Integer> oneToOneHundred = ContiguousSet.create(
    Range.closed(1, 100), DiscreteDomains.integers());
```

I just showed `Integer`s here, but the `Range` stuff works for any `Comparable`. `ContiguousSet` requires a [DiscreteDomain](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/DiscreteDomain.html) for the type... Guava provides `DiscreteDomain.integers()`, `.longs()` and `.bigIntegers()` at the moment.

Answer (score 7):

I have previously [requested this functionality](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=429) and been referred to [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=322). Apparently this functionality will be implemented through Ranges, which will implement `Predicate`.

Answer (score 1):

[`Predicates`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicates.html) collects some common predicates but not a greater than one.  I don't think guava provides such a thing.  You can try filing a bug/feature request at the guava project site : http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/list